# How to upload an image file to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, base64, firebase-storage

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images');
let uuid = uuidv1();
var uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${uuid}`).putString(imageUrl, 'base64', {contentType:'image/jpg'});
```

The code will generate a time-based UUID as the file name, and `imageUrl` is a base64 image file uploaded by users. I use `react-native-photo-upload` to write the upload function. 
Then in firebase, I received a file like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCdVm.jpg)

The image itself is 23.4KB, but what I received in firebase is much larger. How could I get a file-type image from `react-native-photo-upload`? The `onPhotoSelect` only returns base64 image.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `data:image/jpeg;base64` if it is a image url. You can just use `<Image source={{uri: image_url}} />`

Comment: I tried both but they don't work. The file I uploaded to firebase is not an image (it cannot be opened if I download it). So I'm thinking how to get a file through image picker.

Comment: I don’t think Imagepicker would help here.  The downloadUrl should have been able to download and open properly. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part of the code:

```
return (<Image source={{ uri: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + image_url }} />)
```

react native's `Image` component supports only these ways of rendering an image:

First, Local image (i.e. within your project folder):

```
<Image source={require('...')} />
```

Second, Image data (i.e. base64 data, where you already have the data)

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'data:image/jpg;base64,vncowi342r27yvb...' }} />
```

Third, Local Images on user's phones

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'file://...' }} />
```

Fourth, Remote image (i.e. a download URL)

```
<Image source={{ url: 'https://...' }} />
```

The way you're rendering an image does not conform to any of the pattern because for `2`, you must already have to data in order to render the image. So, here are 2 ways of solving the problem

Method 1, If you do not want to change the way you upload your image (which I recommend against, simply because there's a lot more work for you, you'll see why), then, you should have a state called `imageData` that holds the base64 data of the image you want to render, then pass the data to it once's you've fetched it from firebase like so:

```
state = {
    imageData: '',
    ...
    ...
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetchImage()
}

fetchImage() {
    var gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://SOME_ADDRESS')
    gsReference.getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => { return fetch(url) })    // Use react native's fetch API
        .then((response) => { return response.json() })
        .then((data) => this.setState({ imageData: data }))
}

render() {
    const { imageData } = this.state

    return (
        <View>
            {imageData !== '' && <Image
                source={{ uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData }}
            />}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Method 2: Upload your image as a blob with `react-native-fetch-blob` module

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';    

const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
window.Blob = Blob;

// Upload method
// 'path' is the path of the image you want to upload, for example, it
// could look like this: 'file://...', i.e. an image picked from user's phone
function uploadImage(path) {
    let imageFile = RNFetchBlob.wrap(path);
    const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('.../.../.../')
    let uploadBlob = null

    Blob.build(imageFile, { type: 'image/jpg' })
        .then((imageBlob) => {
            uploadBlob = imageBlob;
            return imageRef.put(imageBlob, { contentType: 'image/jpg' });
        })
        .then(() => {
            uploadBlob.close();
            return imageRef.getDownloadUrl()
        })
        .then((url) => {
            // Do something with the url, e.g. store it in database
        })
        .catch(() => { ... });
}
```

Once you've uploaded your images as blobs, you're good to go, render the image like this:

```
<Image source={{ uri: '<url>' }} />
```

Comment: Be a good buddy and accept my answer please :) And, which method did you go with?

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:**
initialize firebase storage setup

**Step-2:** follow this code

```
handleSubmit = (imageFile) => {
const imageUpload = storage.ref(`images/${imageFile.name}`).put(imageFile);
imageUpload.on(
  'state_changed',
  (snapshot) => {
    //process fun here  
      console.log(snapshot);
    }
  },
  (error) => {
     //error fun here 
      console.log(error);       
    }
  },
  () => {
    storage
      .ref('images')
      .child(imageFile.name)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        console.log(url);            
      });
    }
   );
 };
```

return url is our image url